# How to send data (input stream type - not video source ) to rtsp server

Tags: rtsp

I write program to receive data from webcam, afterward I forward it to video frames type and add it to application client - Jframe in Java.
**But now I want to send this frames to rtsp server - with purpose live streaming to other client (same VLC).**
I know that if input is video source so simple, but this way is video frames type.
**So could you help me how to send this data to server RTSP or introduce to me what's server can resolve this issue.**

Thanks & Best Regard.